Случайно MBR перевёл в GPT и теперь у меня полу живой диск без разделов. Как восстановить?
Дело в том, что я случайно MBR перевёл в GPT и теперь у меня полу живой диск без разделов. Arch Linux LiveUSB запускается только в аварийном режиме, а в этом режиме отсутствует как пакетный менеджер, так и утилиты, типа fdisk или parted.
Как мне снова поставить MBR вместо GPT через аварийный режим Arch Linux Live USB? Есть ещё какие-то способы?
Пробовал загрузочную флешку win10, но она говорит, что disk error.

Нести в ремонт. Но уже можно мылиться начинать жизнь сначала. Надеюсь, Вы регулярно выполняли резервирование важных данных на внешние носители? Аккаунты записаны с паролями?

Arch Linux LiveUSB запускается только в аварийном режиме -- это что за режим такой ? впервые слышу

Я так понимаю, речь идёт о режиме загрузки ОС с внешнего носителя. Выражение, написанное невероятно стильно: "MBR вместо GPT через аварийный режим Arch Linux Live USB", по-русски звучит так: "MBR вместо GPT в безопасном (или аварийном режиме) при использовании Arch Linux Live USB".

Конвертация из mbr в gpt не приводит к потере разделов или данных (хотя комп может перестать с него загружаться), так что ты что-то не договариваешь.

Мне помогло следующее:

С другого устройства создать LiveUSB Kubuntu (или Ubuntu, без разницы) в системе GPT.
Установить Kubuntu (Ubuntu), и после этого диск снова живой.

Может помочь и что-то другое, но мне помогло конкретно это.
